# How does java or jvm process/renders graphics

Tags: java, jvm, intel-rendering

I have a problem with rendering swing application as I already asked for help in this thread:
[Java 8 Swing rendering problem with Intel HD 3700 linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52874396/java-8-swing-rendering-problem-with-intel-hd-3700-linux). To summary the whole post I was asking is there any workaround for java to process graphics smoothly when there is integrated intel hd graphics Z3700 (or Intel HD Graphics 2000, 3000, 4000) or any integrated graphics that java has bad rendering, because the graphics goes smoothly on Intel HD 530. Because I bought external nvidia graphics 210 and the problem is still there I thought maybe my problem is something else.

Except my Intel HD graphics, the difference between the development and the production environment is also the processor (cpu Intel Celerom J1900 with Intel HD Z3700, Intel i3 with Intel HD 530). So my question is how does java (in my case i am using Swing) process/renders the GUI, is it on the CPU, integrated GPU or external GPU. Is there anyway I can set or at least check how this is done, either in java, jvm or linux os. I guess that all the rendering is done on the CPU, because adding external graphics card did not change anything.

Comment: Unless you explicitly render to an image in Java, it will use the graphic driver&card as much as possible.

Comment: I monitor my application, with and without external nvidia graphic card. The result is the same. I guess if java tries to render as much as possible there should be at least 1% less cpu usage. Using animated gifs increase my cpu usage on J1900 by 5-7% in comparison to using static images. The same result is with external nvidia graphic card.

Comment: Consider to check your code searching for loops without Thread.sleep, a possible cause of bad render result could be a bad-managed use of cpu and resources in general. Can you show your render code?